# Intercept 401 error in ASP.net Core 2.0 pipeline

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4

In my ASP.net Core 2.0 pipeline, I have the following two configuration entries:

```
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseMvc(...);
```

I wasn't sure which of these generates 401 responses, so I added some custom middleware to see if it was possible to intercept them at various stages:

```
app.Use(async (http, next) =>
{
    if (http.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("intercept!");
    }
});
```

This code would fire after if placed after `UseIdentityServer()`, but not with the 401, and would not fire *at all* if placed after `UseMvc()` in a 401 scenario. That is, `UseMvc()` appears to be ending the pipeline.

Since in one case the error hasn't happened, and in the other it's never reached, how can I go about intercepting these 401s? (And potentially rewriting them)

I also tried a try-catch around the pipeline continuation, placed very early in the pipeline, but this didn't fire either:

```
app.Use(async (http, next) =>
{
    try
    {
        await next();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("intercept!");
    }
});
```

Any ideas on how I can put that intercept in place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this middleware before anything else :

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next.Invoke();

    if(context.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("You seem to have mistyped the url");
    }              
});
```

There won't be any exception for Not found. Default value of StatusCode for a context response is 404. If no middleware modifies the response , 404 will be returned to the client. In this case, we have set up a middleware that allows other middlewares to process the request first by awaiting next.Invoke()..Now, while returning back it checks if StatusCode is still 404 and writes a "you seem to have mistyped the url" message.

Comment: That did it! Obviously modified from 404 to 401. I guess it's the only combination I hadn't thought of; let everything after do its work with an await, and then check the response after.