# How to catch 401 Unauthorized Error and route to new View

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, active-directory, asp.net-authorization

I have been tasked with changing Authorization to use the AD.  Currently the c# application is setup to use role based security using MVC Identity.

Currently the setup.cs file has these configured:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{                
  options.AddPolicy(CollectionsHelper.Policies.RequireEvaluatorRole, policy =>
     policy.Requirements.Add(new RoleRequirement(CollectionsHelper.Roles.Evaluator)));
  options.AddPolicy(CollectionsHelper.Policies.RequireStakeholderRole, policy => 
     policy.Requirements.Add(new RoleRequirement(CollectionsHelper.Roles.Stakeholder)));               
});
services.AddMvc(setup =>
{
   // only allow authenticated users
   var defaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
   setup.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(defaultPolicy));
});
```

Note, I also removed the Authorization attribute decorations on the controllers index functions.

We need to switch to AD groups for this sties authentication.  So I found a post from stackOverflow that got me really close: 
[How to Authorize AD users with .Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895141/how-to-authorize-ad-users-with-net-core)

Following the instructions I am able to use my AD group to access the application, but now I have a new issue.  If I test the opposite and change the domain group to one that I am NOT a member of I get a 401 Unauthorized Error.  I mean yes this is what I want but I would like to utilize a nicer view.  One that has our sites template but with a body that states the user does not have access to this site...Click here to request access...  Something along those lines.

I did go into IIS and changed the Error page routing for 401 to another url (just for testing I did google.com), but the error page still appeared.

Almost forgot to add, I did try the suggestion from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539451/intercept-401-error-in-asp-net-core-2-0-pipeline) but it didn't work.

Comment: Believe what you're looking for might be here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.0#usestatuscodepageswithreexecute